# Trouble with OPAM: External solver failure

Tags: ocaml, opam

Trying to develop with OCaml on Arch Linux 4.12.10, I keep running into this error message:

```
### stderr ###
# error: executing gringo failed (No such file or directory)
# error: gringo returned with non-zero exit status

[ERROR] External solver failure, please fix your installation and check /home/me/.opam/config and variable $OPAMEXTERNALSOLVER.
        You may also retry with option --use-internal-solver
```

This happens for example with these commands:

- `opam init`
- `opam install ocamlfind`
- `opam switch 4.02.3+buckle-master`

Indeed, as the error message says, appending `--use-internal-solver` makes the commands run successfully.

But is there a proper fix for this?

My OPAM version is 1.2.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to install the package [clingo](https://potassco.org/clingo), which contains gringo:

```
sudo pacman -Sy clingo
```

Comment: `aspcud` is probably the most popular external solver, and last I checked, it's available on Arch.

Comment: @RichouHunter: Completely true! But also with `aspcud` installed, I got the error described in the question.

Comment: Either aspcud or opam itself uses gringo, so even with aspcud installed gringo/clingo is required.